# How is there a pg_roles table in Postgres before a database is created?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, roles

I am looking into Postgres and while reading I found that you can check if a user name (to use when using the `createuser` command in command line) already exists in the `pg_roles` table by entering:

```
psql postgres -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'"
```

into the command line. I was just wondering, If I haven't created my own database yet, how are there already existing tables like `pg_roles` and where are they stored/how are they created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `pg_roles` is a view. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/view-pg-roles.html)

> This is simply a publicly readable view of `pg_authid` that blanks out the password field.

And `pg_authid` does not depend on any particular database. It's created when you create the DB cluster. [The documentation once more:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-authid.html)

> Because user identities are cluster-wide, `pg_authid` is shared across
>   all databases of a cluster: there is only one copy of `pg_authid` per
>   cluster, not one per database.